# Convert IOrderedEnumerable to XElement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

the following linq statement returns a IOrderedEnumerable:

```
        var list = from e in ritorno.Elements("dossier")
                              orderby e.Element("name")
                              select e;
```

How can i convert list to XElement?
Thanks

EDIT

list is `IOrderedEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>`

Comment: Yes, but an IOrderedEnumerable of what? As Jon says, do you want a list of XElements, or an XElement with XElements inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a single XElement to contain all the elements in the sequence?

```
XElement element = new XElement("container", list)
```

(Obviously change "container" to whatever you want the containing element to be called.)

If that's *not* what you want, please elaborate.

Comment: this is exactly what i want, but what you suggested gives me a "At least one object must implement IComparable" error ..

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("dossiers", 
                from e in ritorno.Elements("dossier")
                orderby e.Element("name")
                select new XElement("dossier", e.Value));
```

which essentially is what Jon was trying to say ( I think).

Comment: strangely enough, this also gives me the same error "At least one object must implement IComparable"

Comment: Could it be that you must add orderby e.Element("name").Value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
the problem was with the cast of e.Element("name").

The following now works:

```
        var ritornoOrdinato = from e in segnalazioni.Descendants("dossier")
                              orderby (string)e.Element("ANAG_RAGSOC_CGN")
                              select e;
        return new XElement("NewDataSet", ritornoOrdinato);
```